# How to set up communication between two apps in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am currently trying to build a web app Todo task manager with Django as I find that the best way to learn is to get your hands dirty but I have come across a problem and I don't really know what is the Django way of doing it..

At the moment I have two apps in my project, one is 'lists' and the second is 'tasks', and my problem is that on the frontend, I need to show the different lists and associate them the tasks that are related to each list. So far I have managed to get the result visually by giving a list id to my tasks using a foreign key and importing the 'Task' model to the 'lists' views.py to then do the query for tasks within the views.py of the lists app so that I can loop through them on the frontend but I feel like I'm making a frankeistein app now as they are both interdependent

How would you guys handle the situation?

ps: here an excerpt of my code for context

```
from tasks.models import Task


def lists_view(request):
    lists = List.objects.all()
    tasks = Task.objects.all()
    print("The request: ", request)
    context = {
        'lists': lists,
        'tasks': tasks,
    }
    for list in lists:
        print("List: ", list)

    return render(request, 'lists/lists.html', context)


def list_view(request, pk):
    list = List.objects.get(id=pk)
    tasks = Task.objects.all()
    print(request)
    context = {
        'list': list,
        'tasks': tasks,
    }
    return render(request, 'lists/list.html', context)
```

And the html:

```
{% for list in lists %}
<h1><a href="{% url 'list-detail' list.id %}">{{ list.title|title }}</a></h1>
<ul>
    {% for task in tasks %}
    {% if task.list.id == list.id%}

    <li><a href="{% url 'task-detail' task.id %}">{{ task.title|capfirst }}</a></li>

    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do you really even need 2 separate apps? Will lists contain things other than tasks that are so different that you need to separate these things out? You could probably put List and Task in the same modely.py in a single app.

Second, you are going to have some interconnectedness in a case like this. That's okay. Not *everything* needs to be separate and independent.

Now, what do your models look like?

If there are many tasks in a list, you should have a ForeignKey as you mentioned. Something like this (simplified):

```
class List(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    list = ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tasks')
```

Now you can simplify your views:

```
from .models import List

def lists_view(request):
    lists = List.objects.all()
    context = {
        'lists': lists,
    }
    return render(request, 'lists/lists.html', context)

def list_view(request, pk):
    list = List.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {
        'list': list,
    }
    return render(request, 'lists/list.html', context)
```

NOTE: the querysets above should be optimized using prefetch_related() to reduce the number of calls to db
So

```
List.objects.prefetch_related('tasks').all()
```

and

```
List.objects.prefetch_related('tasks').get(id=pk)
```

And you can do the following in your template:

```
{% for list in lists %}
    <h1><a href="{% url 'list-detail' list.id %}">{{ list.title|title }}</a></h1>
    <ul>
        {% for task in list.tasks %}

            <li><a href="{% url 'task-detail' task.id %}">{{ task.title|capfirst }}</a></li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: About the two apps, yeah I was kind of thinking the same and thought I should probably have them both be in a single app as it made less and less sense to keep them separated.
Now for the models, they pretty much look like what you have written already so I glad I got that right ;)

For the queryset, I didn't know that even existed, it makes things much easier than I had set up, how do you find out about those things? I mean the documentation is sooo long, you can't possibly have read it all? haha Anyways, thanks for your answer, it was very helpful!

Comment: Honestly, just lots of reading over time. You should occasionally dig through django docs, particularly if you're trying to implement something unfamiliar. For instance, this page that looks long but is a pretty quick read really (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/) will help you imensely in building queries. I also like to read recent StackOverflow answers, particularly from users like Daniel Roseman (https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman). There are lots of good tutorials out there. Just read and practice, and you'll get there!